# Methods for Payment Gateway Integration in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, payment-gateway, android-developer-api

I have been searching for days to integrate payment method in my Unity Android APP but not getting any positive results.

Please share some method and steps to do so if possible.

Comment: Have you looked here https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/unity

Comment: it's not a game but rather an e-commerce app would the same be applicable

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think it's a good practice to make an e-commerce app with a game engine.

I don't think there are good SDKs to directly use in Unity, available one's can only be used with native code like Java or Kotlin. So what you can do is to use them as native code like in Kotlin then build libraries (.aar files) out of it and later import them into unity to use those APIs directly in your C# code.